# I cannot access QuickBlox Push notifications settings page

Tags: quickblox

I am trying to update our expired iOS notification from the backend. But every time when I try to open the settings page to do that, I get a following error message:

*"We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."*

I filed a Ticket (**#44606**) more than a week ago, but no response yet. Our Advanced plan obviously has less support than the premium ones, but the service I am paying for is not working and there is nothing I can do about it.

I really need to get the notifications to work again on iOS.

Cheers,
Janne

Comment: Hi man, 
sorry for delay, we are checking your account now